# JQGrid client side filter not working for Localized data

Tags: jquery, string, search, jqgrid, localization

I have implemented jqgrid local filter. Working with client data. It is working fine for English but for other languages it is not working.

If I take a special case it is not working for character like ß .

I am using "cn" option. Means it search for contains and it will work till all English like character is there. But once it comes a special character it just not give result.

I don't know where I am missing details. As it is not working for English.

Please let me know if any further details required.

While searching some more I found two basic different in a two grid. One grid it is working and one is not...

Now in the grid in which, it is working, we are adding data using grid inline edit only. While in grid in which it is not working we are adding data using form post out side of the grid. Means in second grid when we press add it will go to another page, where we can add data and then come to page where grid is there.

Now, I suspect there may be difference in encoding of data before posting to the server. But I don't know how jqgrid is posting data. And how I make my form post to post data same as jqgrid.

It will be great help if someone can answer both, but even if someone can give details about jqgrid posting then I can try for later one.

Comment: How you fill the data? (local data, Ajax request to the server, ...)? Can you provide a demo which reproduce the problem. Which `Content-Type"` you has on the page? In which format the page saved?

Comment: @Oleg I filling data from server side. But searching on local data only. Client side only. just give me some time to reproduce demo with dummy data. 
But I didn't get your last question page save format means ?

Comment: I mean the following in the question about format the page saved: let us you work on Windows. You can open the HTML file in notepad.exe, choose "Save As..." in "File" menu and which verify "Coding" value: ANSI, Unicode, Unicode Big Endian, UTF-8. It's encoding format of the file. You should returns UTF-8 encoded JSON data, use "UTF-8" as the file encoding and include `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in the `<head>` of XHTML file.

Comment: @Oleg its <meta charset="utf-8" />

Comment: @Oleg tricky part is I am having two grid one is working and one is not working... I am still not picking up what and where is wrong. So, I haven't put a code also.

Comment: Sorry, but both grids should working. It's difficult to search a bug in the code which one don't see. You can for example save the responses from the server in a text file. Then create HTML page with load the data from the text files. In the way you can create the demo which works *without any server*. If you provide 3 files: htm file and two text files with JSON responses used to fill the grids then one could reproduce the problem and find the origin of it. I am sure that you use just wrong encoding somewhere. One uses `ß` in German language and I had never problems with it in my projects.

Comment: @Oleg can you come up for chat. Or even tweeter handle will do... I have two grids and now I am compering line by line, they are same still they are behaving differently.
Is there anything need to give in colmodels for filter?

Comment: Do you have the solution online?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32565/discussion-between-kunjee-and-oleg)

Comment: @Oleg hey, I added few more details. May be that can help. Let me know if any further details needed.

Comment: Sorry, but I see no sense if you *explain* what you do in the code. One have to *debug* the page which has the problem. You don't post no line of JavaScript code, no line of HTML code and no JSON response returned from the server. One will not goes forward without the information.

Comment: @Oleg I m sorry... I never mean to annoyed you... But I have to pass through from long chain of permission to post code. :(, Still will try and put as much as possible. Thanks for reply...

Comment: @Oleg man... It worked... It was data issue only. On page it was showing ß but originally it was &#223 so it was not searching perfectly. Thanks for finding in comments. Can you do me a favor and please give a answer, even a line will do. I will close the question than.
And sorry for inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked... It is issue with data encoding only. Instead of read data server is passing html encoded data.

So, on page it is showing ß for both 'ß' and &#223. But at the time of putting data in filter we are putting ß. Because of that it can't compare it with &#223, filter stopped working. As data is same from visual point of view it took a little more effort to solve this issue...

Sorry for late reply.